# Need to fetch Metadata from sql query using java

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, metadata, resultset

I have a sql query fro which I need the column name and data type and it's table name and schema name:

Thsi is the  method I am using for using and testing it for SQLSERVER:

```
public static void getMetadataForConn(Connection conn) throws SQLException
    {
        ResultSet rs = null;
         try
         {

             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT AB_DEMO_SRC.dbo.employee.dept_id dept_id, AB_DEMO_SRC.dbo.employee.email_add email_add, AB_DEMO_SRC.dbo.employee.emp_address emp_address, AB_DEMO_SRC.dbo.employee.emp_id emp_id, AB_DEMO_SRC.dbo.employee.emp_name emp_name FROM AB_DEMO_SRC.dbo.employee ");
             ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
             int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
             for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                 System.out.print(md.getColumnName(i) + "(" + md.getColumnType(i) + ") "+md.getSchemaName(i)+"."+md.getTableName(i));
             System.out.println();
             while (rs.next())
             {
                 for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                 {
                     Object o = rs.getObject(i);
                     System.out.print(null == o ? "" : o.toString() + " ");
                 }
                 System.out.println();
             }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != rs)
                {
                    rs.close();
                }
            }
    }
```

I get all the other metadata details like data type, precision and scale..Strangely, I am getting tablename and schema name as "" that is blank..IS there any other way to fetch the metadata of the columns present in a Query?

Comment: Tried by adding sqljdbc41.jar as well..which mentioned that this jar is for jdk7 and jre7, and it has the jdbc api methods implemented.. I really dont understand why the same method returns TableName and ScehmaName for Teradata and DB2 but not for SQL Server and Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the columns of a `ResultSet` are not related to any table, they are related just to the query. The query could be complex, it could have computed columns etc. That is why their table names are blank.

If you want to get the information about the columns of a specific table, you can use the metadata of the database:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet columns = meta.getColumns(null, "dbo", "employee", null);
```

Comment: the method I mentioned in the code works well for other queries , like on from Teradata/DB2, unable to point out why I am not getting the TableName and schema name only for SQLSERVER and ORACLE

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch column name by calling 'getMetaData' method of ResultSet.

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData= resultSet.getMetaData();
String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(1);
```

All other column meta data can also be fetching using object of ResultSetMetaData

Comment: This is exactly what I have done as mentioned in the code,thanks anyway